# Why should abstract class implement an interface?

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

Since an abstract class can contain both complete and incomplete methods, when is it necessary to implement an interface? When should it implement an interface in an abstract class?

Comment: Do some googling for "java, programming to an interface". Essentially, its because when you add methods to the interface, the extensions of the abstract class will not require that those methods be implemented because you will implement them in the abstract class, thus keeping you from having to do a bunch of work just to compile. Think of adding a method to an interface and then having to implement it in 185 child classes. Yuck. Instead, declare the method in the interface, implement it in the abstract class, and leave the child untouched.

Comment: The title of your question will be shown in large, bold type. Making it ALL CAPS is unnecessary and makes it harder to read. (All caps is basically never needed here in the 21st century.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder they are. Memes mate, memes.

Comment: Standard, mate, standards. Don't put your title in all caps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response to my question and thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It is a standard way of how OOP works. Imagine a class `Human`. It is of course **abstract** as there can not be a concrete instance of a human. A concrete implementation could for example be a class `Person` that requires a name and some other information.

```
public class Person extends Human {
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

A common usage of interfaces is to **describe abilities**. In our example we could have interfaces like `CanWalk`, `CanBreath`, `CanJump`, `NeedsWater`, `HasGender` and so on. In such a case a `Human` could implement all of these interfaces, it would be perfectly fine.

```
public abstract class Human implements CanWalk,
    CanBreath, CanJump, NeedsWater, HasGender {
    ...
}
```

Those interfaces now have methods, like

```
public interface HasGender {
    String getGender();
}
```

and `Human` may implement them, but as an abstract human has no concrete gender, it may delegate the implementation to its implementing class `Person`:

```
public class Person extends Human {
    String name;
    int age;
    String gender;

    @Override
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
}
```

On the other hand there might be interfaces where `Human` can offer an implementation, like

```
public interface NeedsWater {
    int amountOfWaterNeeded();
    void drink(int amount);
}

public abstract class Human implements CanWalk,
    CanBreath, CanJump, NeedsWater, HasGender {

    @Override
    public int amountOfWaterNeeded() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Finally we may have classes that work with interfaces. Like

```
public class WaterDistributor {
    public void distributeWaterTo(Iterable<NeedsWater> consumers) {
        for (NeedsWater c : consumers) {
            c.drink(c.amountOfWaterNeeded());
        }
    }
}
```

And you want to be able to pass your humans to that method, so you need to implement the interface.